# Parsing Expression Grammars: detect next token?

Tags: parsing, pegjs

I'm beginning PEG's with `PEG.js`.

There's something I can't get my head around...I'm sure it's simple but it's giving me a headache trying to understand the concept...

Consider this two-rule grammar:

```
name
  = name:.* {return name.join("")}

put
  = "put " a:name " into " b:name "." {put(a,b)}
```

I want to be able to pass this parser "put foo into bar." and cause `put("foo","bar")` to evaluate.

But PEG.js gives me the error `Expected " into " or any character but end of input found.`

I think I could fix this problem if the regex for the `name` rule where more specific than `.*` but why does it have to be? Can't the parser be smart enough to look ahead and see that " into " is coming up, as well as the "." at the end?

How can I achieve what I'm looking for? Is this perhaps the difference between a "bottom-up" and "top-down" grammar?

Edit:
The regex `/put (.*) into (.*)/g` works like I want -- if I pass it `"put foo into bar"`, it gives me `$1="foo"` and `$2="bar"`. I'm just asking if I can get this same functionality (taking the whole string into account before deciding where the token boundaries are) using PEGjs or Jison.

Comment: I don't have personal experience with peg.js, but the online documentation suggests that `.*` will greedily consume every character available to it.

Comment: I'm really curious if someone can comment about this problem in relation to "bottom-up" vs "top-down" parsing. Would it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that "themirror" is correct - the first rule will eat all the input. Try it without that rule.

Also you should have another rule to allow arbitrary spaces. I found this online...

```
_
  = [ \r\n\t]*
```

The underscore will match any number of whitespace characters.
Then you can rewrite your rule as...

```
put
   = "put" _ a:name _ "into" _  b:name _  "." {put(a,b)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad english.

The first rule `.*` try to read every character, so end of file is reached.

You can make name rule more specific (any char but not SPACE or DOT):

```
name = [^ .]+
```

This one works... But not for name with spaces inside.

```
put = "put " a:name " into " b:name "." {put(a,b);}

name = c:[^ .]+ {return c.join("");}
```

For Node.js

```
var PEG = require('pegjs');
var text = 'put foo into bar.';
var parser = PEG.buildParser('{function put(a,b){ console.log(a,b); }}put = "put " a:name " into " b:name "." {put(a,b);}\nname = c:[^ .]+ {return c.join("");}');
parser.parse(text);
```

I have no good solution for spaces in name but try something like this:

```
nameBeforeInto = (!" into ".)+

nameBeforeDot = [^.]+

put = "put " nameBeforeInto " into " nameBeforeDot "."
```

nameBeforeInto return a multi-dimension array

Fabrice